# Android - Activity destruida ao rotacionar o tablet

Tags: android

Estou com o seguinte problema em meu aplicativo:

- Quando o usuário desliga a tela no tablet, liga a tela novamente, gira para a posição vertical e loga no android novamente, a `Activity` que o usuário estava é destruída e volta para a tela de login da aplicação.
- Esse problema só ocorre em `Activity` que possuem uma lista cujo `Adapter` possui um XML que contenha uma propriedade valorada utilizando `@dimen.xml`.

Exemplo:

```
View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_attachment_list_item,
                parent, false);
```

**Meu XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/sp_gen_xl_15dp"
    android:text="@dimen/sp_box_margin_left"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Ou seja: se eu utilizar `android:padding="@dimen/sp_gen_xl_15dp"` para definir o `padding`, a `Activity` é destruída. Se eu passar um valor qualquer "10dp" por exemplo, a `Activity` se mantém quando o usuário realiza o procedimento descrito acima.

Obs.: A `Activity` relatada já possui no **Manifest** a tag `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize` que serve para não destruir a `Activity` quando o *tablet* girar.

**Exemplo:**

```
<activity
     Activity"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

A grande questão é: Por que a *tag* **orientation|screenSize** colocada no **Manifest** só funciona em *Activitys* que **não** utilizam **@dimen** em seus **XML**?

Answer (score 0):

Pra entender o que está acontecendo, é necessário lembrar alguns pontos:

- Você pode ter diferentes xmls dependendo da configuração da tela.
  Por exemplo, pode ter um xml pra quando a Activity estiver em landscape e outro pra quando estiver em portrait.
  Da mesma forma que você pode ter diferentes pastas para diferentes imagens com tamanhos diferentes, você pode ter para os xmls.
  Por exemplo, você pode ter o `meuLayout.xml` na pasta layout e o `meuLayout.xml` na pasta /res/layout-land, onde esse ultimo vai ser usado, automaticamente, quando a orientação do celular mudar para landscape.
- É na instância do `Context` que todas essas variáveis ficam. Existem três implementações de `Context`: Acitivty, Service e o processo do seu app.

Quando a tela gira, o android tem que se re-contextualizar, como você está referenciando um atributo definido num arquivo de recurso, ele vai ter que sempre reinstaciar o `Context`, que no caso é a activty.

Normalmente o `android:configChanges` deve ser usado só em último caso.
O ideal é usar Fragments com o método `setRetainInstance(true)`, como fragments não são implementações de Context, eles não vão ter esse comportamento das activities.

Comment: Percebi que está lançando este erro:
Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute. Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Comment: Ocorre quando giro o tablet e ele tenta dar inflate no XML novamente. A impressão que tive é que o atributo perdeu o valor que veio do @dimen, ou seja, esta vazio.